# Getting sub directories and files using python

Tags: python, directory, python-2.7, directory-structure

What would be the best method of getting sub directories of a drive including files located within them? Would it be best to use `os.listdir()` and filter out directories from files by checking if they have a `'.'` in them?

Any ideas would be helpful, and i would much prefer that i use only the standard library for this task.

Comment: You have given an idea, why have you not tried it? If you have, why didn't it work?

Comment: `os.path.isdir(full_path)` will tell you if something is a directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a look at [`os.walk()`](http://docs.python.org/library/os.html#os.walk), it allows you to visit each directory and get a list of files and a list of sub directories for each directory that you visit.

Here is how you could only go down a single level:

```
for root, dirs, files in os.walk(path):
    # do whatever you want to with dirs and files
    if root != path:
        # one level down, modify dirs in place so we don't go any deeper
        del dirs[:]
```

Comment: The OP seems to want to go only one level down.